# Windows 8 Skype app not showing "away" and "busy" contacts and IM's from those contacts

Tags: windows-8, skype

The Skype Windows 8 app doesn't list red and yellow contacts (busy and away). In my short 24 hour usage experience, it also fails to show incoming messages from these contacts. Is this a bug or are there any settings to be set?

Comment: Just to be clear, I realize I can view ALL CONTACTS, but that doesn't really make a lot of sense when one has over a hundred contacts.

Comment: I would just use the normal Skype application.  My guess this feature is just missing for the time being.

Comment: Yes, use the desktop application. The Modern UI app is beautiful, but that's all there is to it. Even after several updates, every try I make to it reveals unacceptable lacking functions, bugs or design faults. Not to mention that a Modern UI app that's stuck being full screen or pinned as permanently part of the screen is to begin with hardly suited to a desktop PC. Unless you're stuck with it because of Windows RT, the desktop application is a much more practical solution.

Answer (score 1):

In the modern windows 8 app you are unable to set your status as anything else than available and invisible.